# Molar conductivity in compounds showing coordination isomerism

Tags: coordination-compounds, isomers, conductivity

#### Question

> Which of the following complex has lowest molar conductivity?
>
> 1. $\ce{[Co(NH3)6][Cr(NO2)6]}$
> 2. $\ce{[Cr(NH3)5(NO2)][Co(NH3)(NO2)5]}$
> 3. $\ce{[Cr(NH3)4(NO2)2][Co(NH3)2(NO2)4]}$
> 4. $\ce{[Co(NH3)5(NO2)][Cr(NH3)(NO2)5]}$

#### Answer

> 3. $\ce{[Cr(NH3)4(NO2)2][Co(NH3)2(NO2)4]}$

#### My approach

My textbook only has examples of single centered complex ions, unlike what seems to be coordination isomers in the question. Normally, I see stuff with hydrates and ammine ligands which we predict by the number of active anions in the primary valency. But I have no clue on how to proceed with this question and the website does not provide any solution/ reference.

Comment: Hint: Check the ion charges.

Comment: Assuming NO2 to contribute -ve 1 charge, I can see that the third option is +1 -1 coordination in primary valency, while others have higher charges. So since this particular compound having the least charge separation it should have the least molar conductivity, is my logic right?

Comment: If there are ions A+ and B++ of about same size in the same electrostatic field, which would move faster ? Is conductivity proportional to mobility and charge ?

Comment: B++, since it is conductivity is proportional to charge, but I think hydration effects and charge/mass ratio is also involved.

Comment: They are minor to the charge effect, that is higher than proportional. As the ion is faster AND carries bigger charge.